# increase decrease the font size of whole app in angular 6

Tags: css, angular, font-size

I want to change the font size of whole app in one click. like in [this article](https://www.theage.com.au/politics/federal/this-will-drive-people-back-into-the-closet-lgbtiq-warning-on-religious-discrimination-bill-20190910-p52ppz.html)

Right now am trying to archive this by `document.getElementsByTagName()` and get element current font size and increase it. Unfortunately I cannot get the current font size. When I call `document.getElementsByTagName('body').[index].style.fontSize`, returns an empty string. Is there are any packages available to do this..? any suggestions?

Comment: use `rem` as font-size for your elements, and increase the font-size of the `html` element

Answer (score 2):

you can use `[ngClass]` on your wrapper div. I have created a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-font-size-onclick?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for it

the idea is to change the `class` when you click on a button and define your classes with font sizes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion dear, Thing is I have many components with various font sizes, so if am gonna do this I have to do so many modifications in my project. Also it will make it hard to maintain. :(

Comment: what is the difference between changing the body font size and this ? you can wrap your `router-outlet` with a div and apply font size on it

Comment: I guess it's upto @Pumayk_26 for choosing the best way for them self.

Comment: @YashKrishan Yah.. Am just playing with it friend. This might be the solution. But I need to confirm this is the best solution.. Thanks a lot you made my day.. :)

Comment: Cool. Keep us posted.

Comment: @KLTR .. Actually that was an example. I have to get other elements too. like `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`, `document.getElementsByTagName('label')` like that.. all the elements I want to change font size..  :)

Comment: Hi, I would  like to change font size in entire application by overriding component styles,  if were already set. Can anyone of you give me a suggestion on that ?

Answer (score 0):

> getElementsByTagName() will retrieve an array of all element objects
>   with the specified tag name.

Now you have only one body tag and using this function to retrieve it is an overkill and not of much use. It's better to wrap your app with a tag having id like `<div id="myAppView">....app....</div>`

Then selecting the id and applying the modification.

I've created a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k2szyy which has a slight modification of your code using .getElementById()

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

change() {
  document.getElementById('myAppView').style.fontSize = '50%';
}

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myAppView">
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button
(click) = "change()"
>Update</button>
</div>
```

Comment: parentage not working as expected. :( .. I thought 100% means current font size. but its not.. :( ..

Comment: 100 % does mean the original amount. But if you are assigning 100% to the half then it will be half only. For example, to if you change initially to 50% then you want the original amount, assign 200% and not 100%

Comment: problem is initially the font size set as 'px'. not even 'pt'. :(

Comment: I just edited my Stackblitz code, you can save the initial size and restore it when you want.

Comment: [check this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6v5d74) .. In start all the fonts are at 12px. When update, the font size should be the same.

Comment: This is because getElementsByTagName() will only select the outer most elements having that tag, the inner <p></p> tags are not selected.